# Selenium click on required option

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written code for Downloading the files from a site automatically using Selenium but I am facing an issue.
The logic is like it will find the document to be downloaded using xpath then right click on it and then click on save link as and then save it in downloads folder.

[image]

The issue I am facing here is that sometimes instead of clicking on save link as it clicks on the option before save link as ( i.e. open in new window, open in new tab, open in incognito window ) which will not give the desired result according to further logic applied.

I am new to Selenium, please suggest how to avoid this situation and make sure that the correct link is clicked, my code is as follows :-

```
final WebElement Elementform1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(k.toString()));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(Elementform1).build().perform();
Robot robot = null;
try {
    robot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
//robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't you ever get an exception when your code fails to click "Save link as..."? 2. Your code is full of redundant lines. Consider editing it and debug again, as it would be much easier. 3. What browser do you use with Selenium?

Comment: I have just started working on this project, i have not yet implemented which will use these downloaded files and I am not getting any exception